# In general, can a Lagrangian density depend on space-time explicitly?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, noethers-theorem, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

In an exercise on classical field theories, I'm trying to derive the general formula of the Energy-momentum tensor. According to the formula in the lecture notes, this tensor includes a term of minus the Lagrangian density along the diagonal. However, this term does not appear in my derivation unless I assume that the Lagrangian density does not depend explicitly on space-time.

If I do make this assumption, the term appears as a result of partial integration of the term which is the product of the Lagrangian density and the derivative of the variation parameter with respect to a component of space-time. Doing the partial integration gives us the partial derivative of the Lagrangian density with respect to this space-time component times the variation parameter. But, since we assumed that the Lagrangian density does not depend explicitly on space-time, we might as well ignore this term, and again I do not obtain the diagonal Lagrangian density term.

In other words, if we assume that the Lagrangian density does not depend on space-time explicitly, this term doesn't actually contribute to the conservation law, so we might as well ignore it.

So the questions are:

1. Can the Lagrangian density depend on space-time explicitly, and
2. Why does the Energy-momentum tensor have a diagonal Lagrangian term?

Comment: @Qmechanic, thanks for the edit. I actually typed this up on my phone, so it might not be as clear as it could have been.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before going to field theory, it seems instructive to first ask the same questions in point mechanics:

> 1. *Can the Lagrangian $L(q,v,t)$ depend on time explicitly?*

Yes. The Lagrangian $L(q,v,t)$ can depend explicitly on time. E.g. there could be [external sources](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/153302/2451).

On the other hand, if the Lagrangian does *not* depend on time explicitly, then the action has a time translation symmetry, which (via Noether's theorem) leads to energy conservation. Let us from now on assume that this is the case$^1$.

> 2. *Why does the energy function*
>      $$\tag{1}h~:=~p_{i}\dot{q}^{i}-L,\qquad 
>    p_i ~:=~\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}^i},$$ 
>      *have a Lagrangian term?*

Well, the energy is defined to be the Noether charge for the time translation symmetry. One would have to go through the standard Noether procedure/method to derive the standard formula (1) for the energy function. This is e.g. discussed on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) or [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94381/2451) Phys.SE post.

Finally, the above reasoning can be generalized from point mechanics to field theory, where time $t$ is replaced with spacetime points $x^{\mu}$, and where positions $q^i(t)$ are replaced with fields $\phi^{\alpha}(x)$.

--

$^1$ Even in situations with explicit time dependence, we will still use formula (1) as a definition of the Lagrangian energy function, although it will no longer be a constant of motion.

Comment: Alright, we can apply Noether's theorem to derive the energy-momentum tensor precisely when the Lagrangian density does not have an explicit space-time dependence. That makes sense. As for the second question, when I have more time at hand I'll try to make it a little clearer what exactly I have trouble with in the derivation. Thanks for now :)

Comment: Actually, going over my derivation a couple of times, I think I have convinced myself that the remaining problems are just a question of mixing up my partial and total derivatives. I also had a little trouble with whether the boundary term disappears in a partial integration, so if I can't figure that one out, I'll spawn a new question. But other than that, I think it's clear. Thanks for your help!