# Equations of motion for a torqued spherical pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, torque, oscillators

I Want to simulate a spherical pendulum with a torquer on it, i.e. the angles of the pendulum change not only due to torque generated by gravity, but also by a torquer attached to the top of the pendulum, issuing torques $(\tau_\theta,\tau_\phi)$.

I know that for a classical non-torqued spherical pendulum, one can find the equations of motion by writing a Lagrangian:

$$
\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}m(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2+\dot{z}^2)-mgz=\frac{1}{2}m\ell^2(\dot{\theta}^2+\sin^2(\theta)\dot{\phi}^2)+mg\ell\cos(\theta)
$$

but I do not know how to formulate the Lagrangian element corresponding to the added torques on the pendulum.

Edit: I assume that the rod is massless, that it's hanged on one end (and is massless), and that the other end is a point mass with mass $m$. The length of the rod is $\ell$.

Comment: Can you give more details about the pendulum: is the rod/cord massless, ...?

Comment: I added some details about the pendulum that I saw fit. Anything else needed?

Comment: If the torques are non conservative you cannot write a Lagrangian. However you still have Euler-Lagrange equations. [This post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/342294/euler-lagrange-equations-with-non-conservative-force-example/342300#342300) can be helpful.