# The first and second form of Euler-(Lagrange) equation with explicit time dependence

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, differential-equations

I have learned the first and second form of Euler-(Lagrange) equation with no explicit time dependence (the time dependence only implicit on the function to be solved, say $y\left(t\right)$), from Thorton-Marion 5th Edition on Classical Dynamics. I will replace its functional $f\left(y\left(x\right), \frac{d}{dx}y\left(x\right); x\right)$ to this Lagrangian $L$ notation: $$L\left(y\left(t\right), \frac{d}{dt}y\left(t\right); t\right).$$

1. **The first form** of Euler-(Lagrange) equation is solved from the Lagrangian $$L\left(y\left(t\right),\dot{y}\left(t\right);t\right)$$ in Chap 6.3, but with $t$ dependence seems to play no role. Thorton-Marion obtains (6.18):
   $$
   \boxed{\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}-\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{y}}\right)=0}
   $$
2. **The second form** of Euler-(Lagrange) equation is solved from the Lagrangian $L\left(y\left(t\right), \frac{d}{dt}y\left(t\right); t\right)$ in Chap 6.4, but **with explicit $t$ dependence does play a role**. Thorton-Marion obtains (6.39):
   $$
   \boxed{\frac{\partial L}{\partial t}-\frac{d}{dt}\left(L-\dot{y}\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{y}}\right)=0}
   $$
   But this **explicit $t$ dependence** form does not give rise to the correct answer for Euler-(Lagrange) equation with explicit time dependence, because Thorton-Marion used (6.18) already to derive this (6.39). So some modification is necessarily required!!!

### Question

- What are the first and second form of Euler-(Lagrange) equation with Lagrangian of explicit time dependence?
- How to modify and correct the derivations in Thorton-Marion (6.18) and (6.39) to get an Euler-(Lagrange) equation with Lagrangian of explicit time dependent system?

p.s. There is a related post on Lagrange equation with explicit time dependence: [How to deal with explicit time dependence of the Lagrangian?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/437128/how-to-deal-with-explicit-time-dependence-of-the-lagrangian) But they do not work on the analogous first and second form of Euler-(Lagrange) equation. I hope you can provide some insights or explicit final form of equations.

Answer (score 4):

The second form of the Euler-Lagrange equation can be rewritten as

$$ \frac{dh}{dt}~=~-\frac{\partial L}{\partial t},\tag{EL2}$$

where

$$ h(q,\dot{q},t)~:=~\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\dot{q}^j\frac{\partial }{\partial \dot{q}^j}-1 \right)L(q,\dot{q},t) \tag{h}$$

is the (Lagrangian) energy function. EL2 follows directly from the first form of the Euler-Lagrange equations
$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}^j}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial q^j}~=~0, \qquad j~\in \{1,\ldots, n\},\tag{EL1} $$
for an arbitrary first-order Lagrangian $L(q,\dot{q},t)$ with possible explicit time-dependence.

Answer (score 4):

What horrible notation! For an $L$ without expicit time dependence ($L=L(y,\dot y))$, the expression
$$
F= L-\dot y \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot y}
$$
obeys
$$
\frac{d}{dt}F=0
$$
This *first integral* is a  *consequence* of the E-L equation
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}- \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot y}\right)=0.
$$
It is not not a "second form of te E-L equation". In simple exmaples it is the energy, and it says that energy is conserved for time indepenedent sytems. For one-dimensional systems energy conservation is a useful way of solving the motion.

When there is more than one $y$ there is still a first integral
$$
F= L-\sum_i \dot y_1 \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot y_i},
$$
but there is only *one*, and one energy consrevation is not enough to solve the motion.

Similarly if $L(y,\dot y,t)$ then
$$
\frac {d}{dt}F= \frac{\partial L}{\partial t}
$$
is a consequence of the usual E-L equation. The E-L equation *does not change* if there is explicit time dependence.

I suggest you read a better book.

Comment: I suspect that the infelicities you're criticizing in the OP's description are more due to the OP than to Thornton & Marion.  At least in the fourth edition, the notation used is *much* nicer:  the given equation is written out as$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - \frac{d}{dx} \left( f - y' \frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} \right) = 0.$$  The authors also put "second form" in scare quotes, presumably to denote that this isn't really a new form of the Euler equation;  and they basically say what you say in the discussion in that section. ...

Comment: ... It's possible that this changed in the fifth edition, but I kind of doubt it.  Mainly I wanted to defend Marion & Thornton's honor, since it's a pretty good book for intermediate-level classical mechanics (though I usually use Taylor to teach from these days.)

Comment: @Michael Seifert. I guess I'm prejudiced..... I've seen some really bad accounts in intro books.  I learned the stuff from  Synge and Griffith, but learned to love Goldstein.

Comment: I've edited the LaTeX. I hope it's better readable now.