# Solving the most basic constant acceleration mechanics problems with Lagrangian mechanics

Tags: forces, lagrangian-formalism

In the interest of practicing Lagrangian mechanics, I've been trying to use Lagrangian mechanics to solve a set of mechanics problems that usually use Newtonian mechanics to solve. Of particular interest is this problem, with a box of mass $m$ sitting on the ground:

[image: Very basic problem in mechanics]

Using Newtonian mechanics, this is trivial:

$$
a(t) = \frac{F}{m} = \text{const.}
$$

However, if we try to write out a Lagrangian, we end up with:

$$
\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2} m \dot x^2 - U(x)
$$

Now since the box is at ground level, conventionally $U(x) = 0$ (if we define the ground level as the reference point to measure potential energy), thus:

$$
\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2} m \dot x^2
$$

Using the Euler-Lagrange equations:

$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x} = 0
$$

$$
\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot x} = m \ddot x
$$

Which results in:

$$
m \ddot x = 0
$$

Which is clearly not equivalent to the Newtonian case. Now, if we assume a nonzero unspecified potential energy function, then the result would be:

$$
-\frac{dU}{dx} = m \ddot x \Rightarrow \ddot x = \frac{F}{m}
$$

But with the box at ground level, where $U = 0$, this seems to be a contradiction supposed to just make Lagrangian mechanics "work"? Am I differentiating incorrectly or what is wrong with my approach?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/153302/2451